# Get count from SQLITE PCL for a specific month

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am using Xamarin.Forms and C#. I am trying to get the count of Products for each month in a year.

```
string[] months = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

var montlyCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var month in months)
{
      var count = App.Database.GetCount(month);
      montlyCount.Add(month, count);
}
```

Database.cs:

```
public int GetCount(string month)
{
    return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE MONTH(ProductEntryDate) = ?;", month);
}
```

However, there is no such function "MONTH" with SQLite PCL. How can I get the count where month = "January", for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out there is no function like `MONTH()` in SQLite.
The function that you can use to extract the month from a properly formatted date (`YYYY-MM-DD`) is [`strftime()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) which will return a left `0` padded string which is the number of the month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Products 
WHERE strftime('%m', ProductEntryDate) = ?
```

So you must pass as argument a string like `'01'`, `'02'`, ...., `'12'` and not the month's name.

Or you can pass an integer `1`, `2`, ..., `12` if you implicitly convert the return value of `strftime()` to an integer by adding `0`:

```
WHERE strftime('%m', ProductEntryDate) + 0 = ?
```